# Can I share helpful VB.NET code snippets on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I have some [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) code snippets that could be helpful for some people. Can I share them on Stack Overflow?

If not, which place do you recommend me to share them on?

Comment: see: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using CodeTidy (http://codetidy.com/)

Which will allow you to share your code snippets easily.

Share them wherever you like, though when posting it as a question ask "How can I do x?" then answer with your snippet.

Also in addition: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be a good place for you too (as bart said) for reviewing snippets, not for sharing though.

Comment: Thank You for your answer i'll do it

Comment: If you do post it on Stack Overflow, make sure your question is good enough. Self-answering does not imply you can get away with asking a question which would otherwise be closed.

Comment: Yes, good point code snippets that can be found elsewhere easily shouldn't be posted, however if you feel that this would benefit people that can't be found in most places then go for it.

Comment: Code Review should only be used if the OP wants his working code reviewed. It should not be used as a snippet dump just to be able to point people to it.

Answer (score 11):

No, Stack Overflow is not the right place to share such snippets. You might be better off with sharing them on [GitHub](https://github.com/) or something similar.

The only exception ([as juergen d suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143928/can-i-share-helpful-vb-net-code-snippets-on-stack-overflow#comment409692_143929)) would be to self-answer a question using the particular code snippet. If you do so however, make sure that your question is good enough to stand up to scrutiny. Self-answering does not imply you can get away with asking a question that would normally have been closed.

Comment: Thank You for your answer

Comment: But if the snippet solves a problem the user could ask a question and add the answer right away.

Comment: @juergend That would be the sole distinction, yes. But then it really has to be a clear problem the OP faced, which his code solves. If that is not the case, self-answers should not be used for that.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow does have the option to **Answer Your Own Question**, so there are some cases when it's appropriate to essentially share some knowledge you have in the Q&A format provided by the site. However, it's only really appropriate when you are sharing knowledge related to a **very specific** programming problem you've had, not just a general "Hey look at these cool snippets I have!".

If you're looking for a good place to act as a repository for some of these snippets, try the suggestions that Bart and Ryan posted, or consider creating your own blog. On your own blog, you can feel free to post all the articles you want and be however as vague or specific as you would like in regards to your snippets.

Answer (score -3):

I found http://pastenow.tk/ who is better for sharing Code snippets

Comment: Better how? Please expand your answer.

Comment: I agree with Anna, this needs more detail. (This comment exists so that you know one more person to @-notify for possible downvote removal if you edit.)