# How to publish code that cost me many nights to develop and probably someone to serve

Tags: support, site-recommendation

On Stack Overflow the system is based on questions and answers, which makes it difficult to receive a response.

Is there a section where I can upload code that cost me many nights to develop and that I know someone else can serve at the time?

If this section is not found, how could I publish my code?

Comment: Publish the code for *review*, or for telling the world about it?

Comment: If you're asking questions about code the cod in question should be included in these questions directly. Take care to minimize your code that it reproduces the problem your're asking about. Don't  post code, which is irrelevant  for your question. Also this question probably rather belongs to Meta Stack Overflow, not here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is also an acceptable place to ask this question, since it's a site recommendation.

Comment: It's called GitHub.

Comment: @gnat Not a dupe of that question. This question is asking about sharing the code itself, not about sharing it as part of an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by *"someone else can serve at the time"*?

Comment: This question was already asked, here the link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143928/can-i-share-helpful-vb-net-code-snippets-on-stack-overflow casually asks the same thing that I have 6 positive comments and I have -8. This is ironic

Answer (score 9):

No, there is no such section on SE.

Comment: And how can I share my code? For the world to see it?

Comment: @EdgarkRodriguezKeane I have no idea.  I wish you the best of luck finding some means other than SE for accomplishing it though.

Comment: @EdgarkRodriguezKeane GitHub?

Comment: In GitHub I would only see it unless I shared the link, I was referring to some section in StackOverFlow, but someone else had already asked the same question and the answer is that there is no such section.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to publish the code for *review*, we have our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

If you want to tell the world about your code, without specifically asking for *review*, we don't have a section for that here. There are a number of code repository sites out there; I'd recommend [GitHub](https://github.com/).